# Show that $\lim_{x\to |x_0|} \left(x\right) = |x_0|,\,$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

how do i make the correlation that |x-c| < d is equivalent to |x- $x_0$| < d.

Is it as simple as outright stating it or do I need to prove the question via contradiction.

Comment: what is the relationship between $c$ and $x_0$?

Comment: What you have to prove is that $\lim_{x\to a} (x) = a$ for any $a>0$ as $|x_{0}|$ is one such $a$. This is obvious from the definition of the limit. For all $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\epsilon$ and therefore we have, for all $x$ such that $\vert x-a\vert <\delta$, that $\vert x-a\vert<\epsilon$ obviously due to our choice of $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon >0$ you have to find $\delta >0$ such that $| |x| - |x_0| | <\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

**Hint:** Prove that, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ ||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|.$$